# VS2012 - add test missing?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

In VS 2010, I could right click a method and have MSTest create a unit test for me.  Where is this feature in VS2012 pro?

Comment: @Oded - ya, in VS2010 it will also create a unit test project for me with the context menu.  In VS2012 I just added it manually since I did not see the option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran into this myself just now. Here is the explanation:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748493/missing-funtionality-of-creating-a-new-unit-test-from-editor

"The 'New Test' menu does not have any extension points where 3rd party adapters can plug-in. Therefore we decided to remove it. We moved all the New Test Project types into the File -> New -> Project dialog."

So it seems it was removed because it was made for MSTest only, and now they support several frameworks out of the box. But I still miss it as well... Should be able to default to MSTest och NUnit...

Comment: this is absolutely no solution!

Comment: Nope, no solution, just an Answer ;-)

Comment: Although this is the official explanation from Microsoft, please consider marker the response by @SSaurus as the answer.

Answer (score 18):

The command is still there. go to Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard.  Search the shortcuts for createunittests.  The appropriate command comes up in the dialog box.  simply assign it a keyboard shortcut and its ready to go.  Works exactly like the VS2010 once you use the shortcut you created.

Comment: You are a hero for discovering this! I've seen mountains of complaints about this missing feature. It appears it's just hidden and still fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

Should select `Add` not `New` item in FILE menu to add a Test project into current solution.

below steps are copied from [Walkthrough: Creating and running unit tests for managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx)

To create a unit test project:

1. On the File menu, choose Add, and then choose New Project ....
2. In the New Project dialog box, expand Installed, expand Visual C#,
   and then choose Test.
3. From the list of templates, select Unit Test Project.

Hope it helpful.

Comment: This is to create a _project_ whereas the original poster wanted to know how to automatically add a test stub for a specific method or class